# Can I set up a task in ansible to run only if a folder exists?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to set a task in an ansible playbook to run only if a certain folder or a file on the server exist? And if it is possible, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to check if folder exists on server, and it's possible to use this information to control task execution.

```
- name: get stats for a folder
  stat: path=/path/to/folder
  register: stat_result
- name: Doing something if folder exists
  command: do something
  when: stat_result.stat.isdir|d(False)
```

More information:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables
- `|d` is a shorthand for `|default` which provides default value if 'isdir' is not defined.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly how I thought it would look.